# Multiple shared_ptrs to same object, one corrupted

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I wrote a program where I make use of shared_ptr to the store the nodes of a graph. Each node has another object associated which keeps a shared_ptr to the node it belongs to. It seems like this is not the proper way to do it, as the child's shared_ptr to the parent is stuck (the use_count() doesn't increase when I create more shared_ptrs of the parent after construction).

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/oejzAb)

The parent:

```
struct Parent : public enable_shared_from_this<Parent>
{
    Child myChild;

    Parent() : 
        myChild(shared_ptr<Parent>(this)) // can't use getptr() here -> bad_weak_ptr
    {}


    shared_ptr<Parent> getptr()
    {
        return shared_from_this();
    }
};
```

The child:

```
struct Child
{
    shared_ptr<Parent> ptr;

    Child(shared_ptr<Parent> a) :
        ptr(a)
    {}
};
```

Test:

```
shared_ptr<Parent> p(new Parent);
cout << "UC of parent: " << p.use_count() << endl;
cout << "UC of child ptr: " << p->myChild.ptr.use_count() << endl;

shared_ptr<Parent> p2(p);
cout << "UC of parent: " << p2.use_count() << endl;
cout << "UC of child ptr: " << p2->myChild.ptr.use_count() << endl;
```

Output:

```
UC of parent: 1
UC of child ptr: 1
UC of parent: 2
UC of child ptr: 1    // expected 2!
```

I noticed that everything works as expected when I create the Parent through its normal ctor (no new) and get the shared_ptr via getptr(). Can someone elaborate on this? Am I doing something stupid?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Surely you want to pass the child `shared_from_this()` rather than `this`?

Comment: That would give me a bad_weak_ptr exception as there has to exist a shared_ptr of the object for shared_from_this() to work. I tried passing a shared_ptr(this) to the child but the results are the same.

Comment: Child should not have an owning (shred) pointer to the parent because the child will not die until the parent dies (it is a *member* of the parent). You should pass (and store) a *reference* to the parent in the child.

Comment: @Galik that's a very good idea, but I still wonder why that happened.

Comment: It's because you pass the child a raw pointer, so the child's shared_pointer is not initialized from the shared block you created with enable_shared_from_this. The child shared_ptr isn't corrupted, it's discrete/independent.

Comment: As I said, passing a shared_ptr<Parent> to the constructor does NOT change the results.

Comment: Also, imo, a good (safe/performant) design for graphs and networks is to put all your nodes into a container (pref `std::vector`) and express the relationships between them using *raw pointers*. The container manages the lifetime of the nodes so everything gets deleted, no memory leaks.

Comment: @Galik can you briefly elaborate on this? I used raw pointers before, but as the nodes might be exposed I switched to shared_ptr.

Comment: The only reason to use `shared_ptr` is to ensure the node gets deleted when it is no longer being used. Putting the nodes in a container (like a *vector*) has the same effect. Containers are like *smart pointers* for arrays (whole collections) of data.

Comment: In your updated post, you're *still* creating a discrete shared_ptr from the `this` raw pointer. So it's still an independent shared_ptr. shared_ptr doesn't do some magical check to see if the pointer it's being given happens to be a shared pointer, if you give it a raw pointer, it creates a new shared block.

Comment: @kfsone Ah, now I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you created 2 different memory control blocks. One in the child by having it create a shared_pointer to the Parent object, and then by manually creating a shared_pointer using the `newed` pointer instead of calling `getptr()` which in turn calls `shared_from_this` which re-uses the existing control block.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

struct Parent;

struct Child
{
    shared_ptr<Parent> ptr;

    Child(Parent* a) :
        ptr(a)
    {}
};

struct Parent : public enable_shared_from_this<Parent>
{
    Child myChild;

    Parent() : 
        myChild(this)
    {}


    shared_ptr<Parent> getptr()
    {
        return shared_from_this();
    }
};

int main()
{
    shared_ptr<Parent> p = (new Parent)->getptr(); // <-- The mistake was not using shared_from_this here, this creating 2 unrelated use counts for the same object
    cout << "UC of parent: " << p.use_count() << endl;
    cout << "UC of child ptr: " << p->myChild.ptr.use_count() << endl;

    shared_ptr<Parent> p2(p);
    cout << "UC of parent: " << p2.use_count() << endl;
    cout << "UC of child ptr: " << p2->myChild.ptr.use_count() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/727ac4316c52c828) is:

```
g++ -std=c++14 main.cpp && ./a.out
UC of parent: 2
UC of child ptr: 2
UC of parent: 3
UC of child ptr: 3
```

Your first clue for this mistake should have been that after: `shared_ptr<Parent> p(new Parent);` your counts were both 1 and 1, it should have been 2 since you have 2 shared pointers to 1 Parent object.

P.S: That being said, I'm not sure this is the best design for what you're trying to achieve, but that is a whole other question/debate.

Comment: Thanks, now its obvious!